# Help!! Earthing an Engine Coil

Tags: electrical

30+years ago I ran a wire from the coil (can’t remember which HT/LT) via a on/off switch to a earthing point, effectively immobilising the vehicle. Q: is this still possible to do on modern day vehicles? If so which lead do to attach it to?

Answer (score 2):

NO, do not try to earth any of the coil(s) on a modern car - you could easily damage any one of several control units.

However, you could consider putting a switch "in-line" with the fuel pump feed - much safer and will prevent it starting quite neatly.

Answer (score 2):

As Solar Mike states, dont earth your coil(s). Easier yet, most modern cars have fuses which provide power to the coils and/or fuel injectors. Pull either one and the car won't start. Pulling your fuel injector fuse is better, because you won't wash your cylinders during the cranking process.